# Get String value of a Enum in Twincat 3

Tags: plc, twincat, codesys

In Twincat 3 I have a Enum like this:

```
TYPE ENUM_FUNCTIONS :
(
EMPTY                       :=0,    
MOTOR_SPEED_INPUT_1         :=1,
MOTOR_SPEED_INPUT_2         :=2,
MAIN_SHAFT_SPEED_MONITOR_3  :=3,
MAIN_SHAFT_SPEED_MONITOR_1  :=4,
MAIN_SHAFT_SPEED_MONITOR_2  :=5
);
END_TYPE
```

Is there any way to get the String value of the Enum??

For example, use **ENUM_FUNCTIONS[5]** and get the value **MAIN_SHAFT_SPEED_MONITOR_2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/9007204238985227.html&id=) how to do it (only available since **TwinCAT 3.1.4024.x** or **CODESYS 3.5.14.0**)

**TL;DR**, in short, use the `to_string` attribute on the **Enum** and `TO_STRING` function to get the string:

```
{attribute 'to_string'}
TYPE ENUM_FUNCTIONS :
...
END_TYPE

myEnum: ENUM_FUNCTIONS;
str: STRING := TO_STRING(myEnum);
```

Comment: How do I get String in the position 5 of the Enum ??

Comment: `e: ENUM_FUNCTIONS := 4; `
`str: STRING := TO_STRING(e);` Keep in mind that this is only true **if you don't manually specify the enum member values** , because by default the first one will be equal to 0, then 1, 2 and so on!

Comment: Forgot to mention, but if you get any error while trying `e: ENUM_FUNCTIONS := 4;`, then make sure you aren't using `{attribute 'strict'}` on your enum!